# Determining where ambiguous reference is coming from

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I need help determining where 'ambiguous reference' is coming from. When I look at my project, there is no version 3.6.0.1 referenced (directly anyways).
Is there a tool to see how it finds this version so I can resolve this issue?

[image]

When I right click and pick go to definition I get

[image]

Is there a way to tell how each version is associated with this current project?
In references, only 3.6.0.0 is referenced. 
Could this be a VS or resharper6 cache bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue occur when old DLLs are left in the bin directory. Either clean the project or go into the directories in windows explorer and manually remove all files, then rebuild.

Comment: Specifically, "Rebuild Solution" from the Build menu.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I've actually had rebuild solution fail in this case when dealing with versioned DLLs (i.e. SomeVendor.v1.dll). After upgrading to a newer version the old version is sometimes not removed from the bin directory even using rebuild or clean.